# React Native TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to fetch a list of departments from an URL in a React Native application

```
export default function App() {
var [department,setDepartment]=useState([])
const token = /* my token here */

  const getDepartments=()=>{  
    const url = /*my api's url here*/

      return fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + token ,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
      }
      })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

   const getdepartment = async () => {
        await getDepartments().then((res) => {
        console.log('res',res)
          res.map((p, key) => {
            setDepartment([...department,department.push({
              name: p.name,
              id: p.id,
            })])
          });
        });
        console.log(department[0].name) //displays the correct value
      };



           
    
    return (
  <View>
<Button
  onPress={()=>getdepartment()}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
<Text>{department[0].name}</Text> //here lays the problem
              </View>
  )
}
```

here department[0] in JSX is undefined despite the getdepartment() function returning correct department[0]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some misuse of states and arrays in your case, please check the usages of arrays with states and how to update them.

```
const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState(initialArray);


setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getdepartment` its called after the first render happens. So before you press the button "Learn More" `department` is an empty array

Try this:

```
<Text>{(department.length > 0)? department[0].name : ""}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `department` state variable will be an empty array until your asynchronous call has succeeded and replaced it with actual data.

You should display some kind of loading indicator until the data is available:

```js
return <View>
    <Button
        onPress= {() => getdepartment()}
        title = "Learn More"
        color = "#841584"
        accessibilityLabel = "Learn more about this purple button"
    />
    {department.length
        ? department.map(d => <Text key={d.id}>{d.name}</Text>)
        : <Text>Loading departments...</Text>}
</View>;
```

*I've also made it display a `<Text>` tag for every department once it does have the data.*

The second problem is your array initialization:

```js
setDepartment([...department, department.push({
    name: p.name,
    id: p.id,
})])
```

You're adding the result of `department.push` to your array, which is a number. You want to add the object directly:

```js
setDepartment([...department, {
    name: p.name,
    id: p.id,
}])
```

Comment: @coldprogrammmer It won't error because `department` is always an array, but you'll notice that after that call `department` should look like `[dep1, dep2, ..., 123]`. Since you're only reading the first value (using `[0]`) it'll indeed work, but it's still technically incorrect. You'd stumble on that error if you ever tried to use all the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
res.map((p, key) => {
  setDepartment([...department,department.push({
    name: p.name,
    id: p.id,
  })])
```

to

```
setDepartment(res.map((p,key)=>({name:p.name, id:p.id})))
```

Answer (score 0):

First the UI gets rendered and at that moment the department is empty and trying to fetch the name throws error. You can have the check as below

```
{department!=null && department.length>0 && department[0].name!=null &&
 <Text>{department[0].name}</Text> 
}
```